# Multiple nodered containers with docker and nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, node-red

I have some configuration where  users can create nodered instances using **docker** containers , but i've used one docker container for each instance and i've used nginx as reverse proxy.
Thus where i need to know how much *containers* can be created in one network and if the number is limited how can i increase it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible answers to your question:

1. I dont think Nginx will limit the amount of NodeRed instances you can have.
2. If you are working on 1 machine with 1 IP address you can change the port number for every NodeRed instance so the limit would be at around 65,535 instances (a little lower as a few ports are already used)
3. If you are using multiple machines (lets say virtual machines) with only 1 port for NodeRed instances, you are limited to the amount of IP addresses in your subnet.
   In a normal /24 subnet (255.255.255.0) there would be 254 IP addresses.
   **3.1.** You can change your subnet in your local network.
   https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/subnet-cheat-sheet-24-subnet-mask-30-26-27-29-and-other-ip-address-cidr-network-references/
4. If you are using multiple machines and are using a wide range of available ports, you have nearly no limit on how many instances you can deploy. The limit would be your hardware i think.

Comment: Just to add to this, you **WILL** run out of memory/cpu on a host machine before you run out of ports

Comment: @hardillb how can i check the number of container that my host machine can handel before it will run out of memroy/cpu

Comment: You test it, because it will be entirely dependent on your workload. Once you know how much each instance needs you can set resources limits on each container. P.s. rather than reinvent the wheel, you could just use FlowForge (I work for FlowForge)

Comment: @Fabian Thank u for this information , I think the 3rd one is my case and i have a subnet of /16 with only 1 port for NodeRed so i think the limit would be at around 65,535 instances , so if this is right how can i increase this and could you plz explain the 4th one a little bit

Comment: To increase your subnet you would need to change your subnetmask to /15 or lower (/14, /13, ...), you should be able to change this in your router, but im not a 100% sure how to do this exactly, SRY

Explanation 4: If you use multiple machines lets say 5 machines, and use all the available ports, you could already run about 300k Nodered instances (number of machines you are using * number of usable ports on the system)
Like this:  
Nodered 1 running on 192.168.1.2:9000,
Nodered 2 running on 192.168.1.2:9001,
.... ,
Nodered XX running on 192.168.1.6:12000,
and so on

Comment: @FabianHintringer thanks for your answer, i already tried changing the subnet mask but it says you can't use this range or something cuz it is already in use by another network i guess